Alternative definition of inf-embeddable in TREE(n)
I am trying to come up with an explanation of TREE(n) for kids, and I need to come up with an explanation for what it means when a tree "contains" another, or "inf-embeddable" as stated on Wikipedia. To my understanding, a tree A contains a tree B if we can form B by removing nodes one at a time from A, making the children of a removed node children of the removed node's parent, with the additional requirement of preserving all nearest common ancestors of all pairs of nodes. If so, is it possible to replace the last requirement with the requirement that only nodes with at most one child can be removed?
